# Given a particular solution, how do I solve $x' = (1+t^2) - 2tx +x^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a particular solution $x_1 = t$, how do I solve $x' = (1+t^2) - 2tx +x^2$? I think it may have to do something with the solution for the homogeneous equation, but I'm having problems with solving that. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks for the answer, Simon. Why was the particular solution not needed?

Comment: The equation is not linear in $x$, so adding homogeneous solutions is not going to work for you.

Comment: See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#Obtaining_solutions_by_quadrature). It explains how to integrate the Riccati equation when a particular solution is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that we can rewrite the equation as

$$x' = x^2 - 2tx + t^2 + 1 = (x - t)^2 + 1$$

or

$$(x - t)' = (x - t)^2$$

So substitute $u = x - t$ and we have $u' = u^2$ hence $1/u = -t + c$ or

$$x(t) = \frac{1}{c - t} + t$$